# git + gerrit branch internals

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm new to Gerrit and I want to understand Gerrit from a Git-internals persective.

In my company's Gerrit setup, I can download a current Gerrit-branch with the following Git command

`git fetch ssh://user@company.com:12345/company/department/project refs/changes/12/123456/3 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

What this does, in my company's configuration, is to download a particular Gerrit-branch of a Git project.

To be clear, the above is NOT a **git branch**; I use the phrase **Gerrit-branch** on purpose.

When I `git clone ssh://user@company.com:12345/company/department/project` and then `git branch --list -a` I only see

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/stable
```

But in the Gerrit web interface, I see dozens of **active** Gerrit-branches.

**QUESTION**

1. How does Gerrit store a Gerrit-branch inside the Git server?
2. Is `refs/changes/12/123456` a detached branch i.e. [no parent pointer](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) to anything in the tree containing the "base" node?
3. Are these Gerrit-branches invisible to `git branch --list -a` because of the custom scheme from Q1?
4. How can I get a list of the `refs/changes/12/123456/3` available on the remote server?
   Running `tree .git/refs` gives me only two "refs" files: `heads/master` and `remotes/origin/HEAD`